# Background Worker for a big SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, backgroundworker, .net-3.5

I have a big SELECT statement and it takes a little while to show the info.

I want to know if it's possible to run the SELECT statement (or any SQL query for that matter) on a background worker in C# and show "something" to the user to them know the program is working and they have to wait. Something like: http://linux.m2osw.com/sites/linux.m2osw.com/files/images/waiting-wheel-300x300.gif

Is it possible to run the query and show something similar to that .gif while the query it's been run on the background? Or should I just change the cursor to Wait before the query it's ran and change it back afterwards?

The .NET Framework is 3.5.

Thank you.

PD: I'm not asking you to do it for me, I'm just asking if it can be done and how complex it would be.

Comment: Ai ... too bad you're on 3.5. This is a great case for all the -Async methods in EF6.

Comment: By assuming that query is executing through a stored proc you can call it in a UI Thread and delegate a progress control to update user with status

Comment: What type of application are you talking about anyway? Web app or something else?

Comment: @spike It's a desktop app, but the SELECT query is too big and take its time and I don't want users to come up with the classic "This is doing nothing!" while they wait. At least with something to let them know the app is indeed doing something (like that .gif), they won't say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLCommand.BeginExecuteReader method. You create a reference to an AsynchCallback method to handle things when then thread is done processing the query. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc.aspx